Error : Conversion 'rpy2py' not defined for objects of type
I am using python R library to implement the ERGM model to a data set. I am following the below approach
def ergm_process(nodes, edges):
    try:
        logger.debug(f"Passed Node: {nodes}")
        logger.debug(f"Edges: {edges}")
        
        # Convert node and edge data for R
        nodes_df = pd.DataFrame(nodes)
        edges_df = pd.DataFrame(edges)

        nodes_df['Attendance'] = pd.to_numeric(nodes_df['Attendance'], errors='coerce')

        if 'id' not in nodes_df.columns:
            logger.error("Node data must include 'id' keys")
            return {"error": "Node data incomplete"}


        # R DataFrame Conversion
        nodes_r = pandas2ri.py2rpy(nodes_df)

        # Prepare node and edge data for R
        node_ids = nodes_df['id'].tolist()
        edges_tuples = [(edge['from'], edge['to']) for edge in edges]

        # Log and check edge tuples
        if not all('from' in edge and 'to' in edge for edge in edges):
            logger.error("One or more edges are missing 'from' or 'to' keys")
            return {"error": "Edge data incomplete"}

        flat_edges = [item for tup in edges_tuples for item in tup]

        # Setup R environment
        from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
        base = importr('base')
        network = importr('network', on_conflict="warn")
        ergm = importr('ergm', on_conflict="warn")

        # Pass data to R
        ro.globalenv['nodes'] = nodes_r
        ro.globalenv['node_ids'] = ro.StrVector(node_ids)
        ro.globalenv['edges'] = ro.IntVector(flat_edges)  # Flatten list of tuples

        # Run R code
        ro.r('''
        print("Node IDs:")
        print(node_ids)
        print("Edges:")
        print(edges)
        net <- network::network(matrix(edges, byrow=TRUE, ncol=2), directed=TRUE, vertices=node_ids)
        # Ensure each attribute is set
        for (attr_name in colnames(nodes)) {
            set.vertex.attribute(net, attr_name, nodes[[attr_name]])
        }
        print("Network created with attributes:")
        print(list.vertex.attributes(net))
       
        fit <- ergm(net ~ edges + triangle + mutual + nodecov('Attendance'), 
            estimate = "MPLE")
        print("Model fitted")
        print(summary(fit))
        ''')

        results = {}
        summary = base.summary(ro.r('fit'))

        # Getting the summary of the fit
        fit_summary = r['summary'](ro.r('fit'), output='summary')  # Ensure to get summary as a dataframe-like structure

        # Convert R summary object to pandas DataFrame if possible
        
        summary_df = pandas2ri.rpy2py_dataframe(fit_summary)
        logger.debug(summary_df)

        # Prepare results for JSON serialization
        results = {
            "Estimates": summary_df["Estimate"].tolist(),
            "Std. Errors": summary_df["Std. Error"].tolist(),
            "MCMC %": summary_df["MCMC %"].tolist(),
            "Z-values": summary_df["z value"].tolist(),
            "P-values": summary_df["Pr(>|z|)"].tolist(),
        }

        return results
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception("Error during ERGM process: %s", str(e))
        return {"error": str(e)}

When I implement that code I get the  Conversion 'rpy2py' not defined for objects of type error
I tried to implement the following method
But when i approach it it gives the error related to fit_summary$se saying that the arguments are 4,0
Maximum Pseudolikelihood Results:

                     Estimate Std. Error MCMC % z value Pr(>|z|)    
edges              -11.728186   1.263969      0  -9.279   <1e-04 ***
triangle             2.088686   0.108218      0  19.301   <1e-04 ***
mutual               8.638105   0.817793      0  10.563   <1e-04 ***
nodecov.Attendance  -0.034097   0.007857      0  -4.339   <1e-04 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Warning:  The standard errors are based on naive pseudolikelihood and are suspect. Set control.ergm$MPLE.covariance.method='Godambe' for a simulation-based approximation of the standard errors.

     Null Pseudo-deviance: 1.469e+09  on 1.059e+09  degrees of freedom
 Residual Pseudo-deviance: 1.051e+03  on 1.059e+09  degrees of freedom
 
AIC: 1059  BIC: 1134  (Smaller is better. MC Std. Err. = 0)

# Adjust the R script for better compatibility and error handling
ro.r('''
library(ergm)
net <- network::network(matrix(edges, byrow=TRUE, ncol=2), directed=TRUE, vertices=node_ids)
for (attr_name in colnames(nodes)) {
    set.vertex.attribute(net, attr_name, nodes[[attr_name]])
}

fit <- ergm(net ~ edges + triangle + mutual + nodecov('Attendance'), estimate = "MPLE")

# Check if fit is valid and prepare summary
if (!is.null(fit)) {
    fit_summary <- summary(fit)  # This should be the raw summary output
    if (!is.null(fit_summary)) {
        fit_df <- data.frame(
            Estimate = fit_summary$coefficients,
            Std.Error = fit_summary$se,
            Z.value = fit_summary$coefficients / fit_summary$se,
            P.value = fit_summary$p.values
        )
        print(fit_df)
        .GlobalEnv$fit_df <- fit_df  # Save DataFrame to global environment
    } else {
        print("Fit summary is NULL or not available.")
    }
} else {
    print("ERGM model did not fit properly.")
}
''')


if 'fit_df' in ro.globalenv and not r['is.null'](ro.globalenv['fit_df']):
            summary_df = pandas2ri.rpy2py(ro.globalenv['fit_df'])
            results = {
                "Estimates": summary_df["Estimate"].tolist(),
                "Std. Errors": summary_df["Std.Error"].tolist(),
                "Z-values": summary_df["Z.value"].tolist(),
                "P-values": summary_df["P.value"].tolist(),
            }
            return JsonResponse(results)
        else:
            logger.error("Model summary is NULL or the DataFrame could not be created.")
            return JsonResponse({"error": "Model did not converge or insufficient data for summary"}, status=500)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception("Error during ERGM process: %s", str(e))
        return JsonResponse({"error": str(e)}, status=500)


always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.
